# Is it possible to load and run script in the src of an html img tag?

Tags: javascript, html, security, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am building an application (not for production, kind of exam) which stores images in firebase storage and i do not know how to protect them correctly with security rules, because firebase does not maki it possible to read info (allowed members to access resource) from the firestore database.

So i was thinking what is the biggest threat to let the images be open without security rule. It can be spammed with unwanted image, someone else can get them. Those images are not really  high value ones, so it does not matter if that got corrupted.

But got in my mind if someone changes an image to be a script and client tries to load it in html img tag, what can happen?

What other threats do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run code by injecting it into an img tag. That would be a massive security hole in the browser (which was actaully a problem in some browser in the distant past).

Firebase Storage download URLs are always accessible to anyone who has the URL.  Security rules do not apply.  The only way to stop that is to revoke its token in the Firebase console, which makes the URL stop working for everyone.

If you want to impose some security on a URL used to load an image, the URL will need to be served by some backend code that checks whatever permissions before sending the contents of the image to the client.

Comment: It would not be a problem to someone has access to it.  But it would if someone could replace or delete it.